# How do I use variables in a UIColor?

Tags: swift, variables, uicolor

What type of variable should I be using for UIColor() and
Why won't this code work?
I am trying to using variables created in a different class to be the amounts for red, green, and blue.  I did the variables the same for all the colors but get the error: 'extra argument green in call'

```
import UIKit

class Color: UIView
{
    var colors = ViewController()

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
    {

        let swiftColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 165/255, blue: 0, alpha: 1);

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0)
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,
            UIColor(red: CGFloat(colors.red1), green: CGFloat(colors.green1), blue: CGFloat(colors.blue1), alpha: 1.0))
        let rectangle = CGRectMake(60,170,200,80)
        CGContextAddRect(context, rectangle)
        CGContextStrokePath(context)
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context,
            UIColor(red: CGFloat(colors.red1), green: CGFloat(colors.green1), blue: CGFloat(colors.blue1), alpha: 1.0))
            CGContextFillRect(context, rectangle)
    }
}
```

Comment: Give UIColor(red: CGFloat(colors.red1), green: CGFloat(colors.green1), blue: CGFloat(colors.blue1), alpha: 1.0)).CGColor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
class Color: UIView
{
    var colors = ViewController()

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
    {

        let swiftColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 165/255, blue: 0, alpha: 1);

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0)
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,
            UIColor(red: CGFloat(colors.red1), green: CGFloat(colors.green1), blue: CGFloat(colors.blue1), alpha: 1.0).CGColor)
        let rectangle = CGRectMake(60,170,200,80)
        CGContextAddRect(context, rectangle)
        CGContextStrokePath(context)
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context,
            UIColor(red: CGFloat(colors.red1), green: CGFloat(colors.green1), blue: CGFloat(colors.blue1), alpha: 1.0).CGColor)
            CGContextFillRect(context, rectangle)
    }
}
```

`CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor` expects a `CGColor` as parameter, but you are providing `UIColor`.

Comment: UIColor(red: CGFloat(colors.red1), green: CGFloat(colors.green1), blue: CGFloat(colors.blue1), alpha: 1.0).CGColor

Comment: Append .CGColor to the color